# Magento JavaScript error: TypeError: source is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I am getting a JavaScript error in Magento:

```
TypeError: source is not an object
properties = Object.keys(source);
```

I am trying to use jQuery and I'm making use of  noConflict() so that it doesn't conflict with ProtoType, like so:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {

    // jQuery code here.

})(jQuery);
```

I'm new to Magento and have never used ProtoType. What could be causing this issue?

Here are a few screenshots that may help debug this:

[image]

[image]

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Somewhere in the code it looks like you're calling [`addMethods`](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/e3d5200cef3236b257ddcfb1eb3eabc5c586bedd/src/prototype/lang/class.js#L126) but the parameter being passed in is not an object. You should grep your code to find out where this method is being called.

Comment: it would be helpful to know when/where does that error occur and the code that is executed